# $P, Q$ and $R$ are prime numbers. $P + Q = R$ and $1 < P < Q.$ What is the value of $P$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, prime-numbers

Attempt:

$P + Q = R$

$P + Q - R = 0 $

$1 < P < Q$

$1 + Q < P + Q < 2Q$

$1 + Q < R < 2Q$

I am lost...

The sum of two primes minus a third = 0 could be anything!

Comment: The difference of two primes is even, unless the second one is $2$.

Comment: If R=2 then P and Q are pair of twin primes where P is negative with your condition, however by definition, negative integers cannot be prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: If both $P$ and $Q$ are odd, then $R$ is an even prime greater than $2$. That is impossible, so one of $P$ and $Q$ must be an even prime. Can you continue from there?

Comment: How do you know there isn't and even prime greater than 2?

Comment: Any even number $N$ greater than $2$ is divisible by $2$, with $N=2M$ for some $M>1$. So it can't be prime.

Comment: Recall Monroe’s Conjecture that [8 is the largest even prime](https://xkcd.com/899/).

Answer (score 2):

Since sum of two primes is $P$ and $Q$ prime greater than 2, then $R$ is odd, so one of $P$ and $Q$ them must be even. Since only even prime is $2$ and $P$ is smaller one (betven $P$ and $Q$) we have $P=2$.

Comment: How do you know that there are no even primes greater than 2?

Comment: 2 is the only one even prime number.

Comment: @user9995331 Think about how you can factor an even number ...

Answer (score 1):

$P = 2. \tag 1$

For, with

$P > 2, \tag 2$

we have that $P$ is odd;  since $Q > P$, $Q$ is also odd.  Then since

$R = P + Q, \tag 3$

$R$ must be even; but there is no even prime greater than $2$.